# Post URL Params to a zapier webhook through Javascript and redirect to different URL

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, parameters, query-string

So I have a few issues that I am trying to overcome. To start I can't just use a zapier webhook because I need to be able to redirect information.
Basically data comes in on querystring (utms, click ids, affiliate custom params, etc) and I have this code that works in a NON case sensitive ways, so when affiliates us CLICKID or clickid or ClickID it doesn't work. I am unsure how to change it to regex. There is also a form with input fields matching these id's not posted as it includes api information.

```
function fillFormName(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_field_FirstName');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const name = urlParams.get('inf_field_FirstName');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = name;  // fill the form with the name
}
function fillFormEmail(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_field_Email');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const email = urlParams.get('inf_field_Email');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = email;  // fill the form with the name
}
function fillFormlid(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_field_LeadSourceId');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const lid = urlParams.get('inf_field_LeadSourceId');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = lid;  // fill the form with the name
}
function fillFormUTMS(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_custom_utmsource');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const UTMS = urlParams.get('utm_source');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = UTMS;  // fill the form with the name
}
function fillFormUTMM(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_custom_utmmedium');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const UTMM = urlParams.get('utm_medium');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = UTMM;  // fill the form with the name
}
function fillFormUTMCa(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_custom_utmcampaign');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const UTMCa = urlParams.get('utm_campaign');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = UTMCa;  // fill the form with the name
}
function fillFormUTMT(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_custom_utmterm');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const UTMT = urlParams.get('utm_term');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = UTMT;  // fill the form with the name
}
function fillFormUTMCo(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_custom_utmcontent');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const UTMCo = urlParams.get('utm_content');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = UTMCo;  // fill the form with the name
}   
function fillFormAffClick(){
  
  const input = document.getElementById('inf_custom_AffClickID');  // find the element name
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);  //parse the query string
  const AffClick = urlParams.get('clickId');  // Store the parsed name in variable

   input.value = AffClick;  // fill the form with the name
}   
if (document.readyState === 'loading') {  // Loading hasn't finished yet
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormName);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormEmail);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormlid);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormUTMS);  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormUTMM);  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormUTMCa);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormUTMT);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormUTMCo);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fillFormAffClick);
} 
else {  // `DOMContentLoaded` has already fired
  fillFormName();
  fillFormEmail();  
  fillFormlid();
  fillFormUTMS();
  fillFormUTMM();
  fillFormUTMCa();
  fillFormUTMT();
  fillFormUTMCo();
  fillFormAffClick();
}
```

I have tried replacing with an overall regex code that pulls all params vs calling each one, but it then won't pickup any parameters in it.

Basically I need to be able to capture anything coming in whichever case sensitivity it comes in as. So https://foo.bar?e=7&utm_source=places&clickid=123abc as well as https://foo.bar?E=7&UTM_source=places&ClickID=123abc